# Script to replace variables used in simulink blocks with a value

Tags: matlab, simulink

Is there a way to replace variables used in a Simulink block with actual values stored in the Matlab base workspace (or model workspace) ?

e.g.
In a gain block, the 'Gain' parameter is set to 'gain_A'.
'gain_A' is defined in the base workspace to '0.5'.
Intended script will replace 'gain_A' in the gain block with'0.5'.

A method that I've tried is to use `Simulink.findVars(modelname, 'Name', 'gain_A')` which will return an object that contains a property with all the blocks that uses the variable 'gain_A'. However, it doesn't tell me which parameter it is used for (e.g. 'Gain').

Appreciate your help =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this will work, but can you combine `Simulink.findVars` with `get_param` to get all the block parameters for each of the blocks identified by `Simulink.findVars`? As per [Get a Block Parameter Value and Attributes](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/get_param.html#btqy0m7-2):

```
block_parameters = get_param(block_path,'DialogParameters')
```

You could then figure out which parameter each variable (e.g. `gain_A`) is used for.

Comment: Thanks! I think this would work. I'm just a little worried about the performance for large models as I will need to loop through each dialog parameter to find for the corresponding variable. Do you know if there is a way to manually resolve symbols as is done  during compilation? [link](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/simulink/ug/resolving-symbols.html)

Comment: Sorry, no. I have to confess I didn't even know about resolving symbols during compilation. *hangs head in shame*

Comment: No worries! Thanks for your suggestion. I will give it a go and see how it performs.